# Single SSL Certificate, Multiple Sites?

Tags: security, ssl, authentication

I asked this as part of another question but feel like it should have its own:

With a shared hosting plan, is there any way to secure multiple domains (assuming the host allows multiple domains under a single plan) with a single SSL certificate?  I know that private SSL certificates require a dedicated IP but I am looking for work-arounds (I'd rather not sign up for extra/better plans to keep costs cheap and I really do not want to outsource authentication..as in with OpenID).  Any ideas?

(I don't think wildcard certs are an option as they are very expensive...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically no, not in a shared hosting plan.

When you have multiple web sites sharing an IP the server knows which site to route to by the Host header. SSL encrypts the entire request and response, including the host header - and a web server does not know which SSL certificate to use to crack open the message before attempting to route it - this is why an SSL site must have a dedicated IP address.

Comment: The Server Name Indication (SNI) extension to TLS allows TLS sites to share IPs. Unfortunately it seems unlikely cheap hosting providers would support that, because the providers typically want to charge extra for dedicated IP. Supporting TLS for virtual hosts could also cause the providers to be able to serve fewer customers with same hardware because TLS processing takes extra resources.

Comment: This question is old now, but for those looking for a quick answer: a majority of browsers (96%) support SNI now (https://caniuse.com/#search=sni), so you can use a single certificate at one IP for different domains.

Answer (score 3):

Like I mentioned in your other question, just ask your host for a dedicated IP for each domain that needs SSL. That's a fairly basic request. If they can't do that, then perhaps it's time to go shopping for a different host, as it seems you've outgrown what your host can provide for you.

Answer (score 1):

As for costs: whether certificates cost you anything depends on whether you use self-signed ones, or certificates from a free CA, or certificates from an expensive CA. Of course, for self-signed or free CAs, your users would have to confirm that they trust the CA in the web browser. Take a look at [CACert](http://www.cacert.org/) for inexpensive certificates.

As for your original question: the approach recommend by RFC 3280 is to fill all the host names into the subjectAltName extension, see section 4.2.1.7 of the RFC. Whether or not a CA is willing to issue to you a certificate with that extension filled out depends on the CA again.